# metadata from images on nutch 2x

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

I have recently using working on nutch, some far I go its crawl some site and images, I had crawl metadata too but just some site. I want metadata from images. 
is some way to get metadata from images? I using nutch 2x and solr 4.8.1

this my nutch-site.xml, suffix-urlfilter.xml and regex-urlfilter.xml
http://picturenutch.blogspot.com/2015/09/nutchsite.html

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: hi raptor,what i had done so far is ---> http://picturenutch.blogspot.com/2015/09/nutchsite.html that's my configuration on nutch